# is it possible to uploading images on subdomain in wordpress blog...?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I want to upload image in sub domain in my site.

When I am uploading image in site, its path is like this,

> http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/image.jpg

But I want to be like this,

> http://www.sub.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/image.jpg

is it possible in WordPress ?

Please give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Check the site url in wordpress database.

Check the options table. The first entry will be the site url. Check the value of site url there and verify that it corresponds to the subdomain. If not change it and try re uploading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But when i upload image from admin panel, url automatically change to subdomain.